# Adapt Praktica MTL 5B lenses to Lumix G80 camera

Tags: lens, lens-adapter, old-lenses, mirrorless, praktica

I recently bought a Panasonic Lumix G80 12-60 mm/F3.5-5.6 kit lens as my first proper camera (apart from point and shoot cameras). I've also found some lenses that belonged to my dad, that were used on a Praktica MTL 5B film camera. The lenses are the following (click for higher res):

[image: Praktica MTL 5B 50mm/F1.8 Kit Lens]

<sup>*Praktica MTL 5B 50mm/F1.8 Kit Lens*</sup>

[image: Sigma 70-210 mm/F4-5.6]

<sup>*Sigma 70-210 mm/F4-5.6*</sup>

They were stored unused for around 20 years on a photographer's bag, inside a closet in our home. They seem to be in good condition, no scratches on the glass (for what it's worth, I've looked through the viewfinder and the image seemed fine), although the house is prone to humidity getting in so I don't know if that could be an issue.

While I've studied quite a bit about digital photography, I'm very unexperienced about film/vintage stuff, so I hope someone could help me regarding these questions:

1. Are there any adapters for this lenses to the <strike>L mount</strike> MFT mount that are relatively cheap (less than 50€)?
2. When adapted, what will be the actual Focal Lengths and Apertures in the M43 system?
3. I'm aware that those lenses are manual focus only, but will I still get Zebras, Magnification and the likes?
4. Is the quality of those lenses, after adapting, at least acceptable, or is not worth the investment/trouble?

Comment: Short answer... Yes, you can get an adapter for that.

Comment: Long answer... [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any adapters for this lenses to the L mount MFT mount that
> are relatively cheap (less than 50€)?

Yes. You probably need an M42 to micro four-thirds adapter.  [Fotodiox makes inexpensive ones](https://fotodioxpro.com/products/m42-mft).  You will, of course, lose the ability to control focus and aperture from the camera body (no electronic communication) and there won't be any lens EXIF information (aperture used, focal length, etc.)

See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

> When adapted, what will be the
> actual Focal Lengths and Apertures in the M43 system?

The focal length and max. apertures remain what's printed on the lenses.  What changes is the field-of-view, and the depth-of-field, vs. those lenses being used on a full-frame/35mm film camera.  But focal length is a physical property of the lens that doesn't change just because you put a smaller sensor behind it.  And the max. apertures remain the same for exposure purposes.

The field of view a 50mm lens on micro four-thirds will be similar to that of a 100mm lens *on full frame* (double the focal length), but its focal length and magnification remain those of a  50mm lens.  And f/1.8 on micro four-thirds yields a similar DoF that f/3.5 would on a full-frame 100mm lens (two stops smaller).

> I'm aware that
> those lenses are manual focus only, but will I still get Zebras,
> Magnification and the likes?

Yes.  Also focus peaking.  These are done by the camera processor on the sensor data, and that does not require communication from the lens.

> Is the quality of those lenses, after
> adapting, at least acceptable, or is not worth the investment/trouble?

Depends on how picky you are and what your taste in lenses is like. But mostly, yes, it should be decent.  Smaller sensors tend to crop off the corners, where performance is weakest.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any adapters for this lenses to the MFT mount that are relatively cheap (less than 50€)?

Search on your favorite auction site for "M42 MFT adapter".  Sort by price.  Consider limiting results to local sellers.  Another option is to pair an M42-EF adapter with an EF-MFT adapter, which would open up some other options (other mounts, focal reducers).

> When adapted, what will be the actual Focal Lengths and Apertures in the M43 system?

The focal lengths and apertures will be as marked on the lens.

> I'm aware that those lenses are manual focus only, but will I still get Zebras, Magnification and the likes?

Focusing aids work with manual lenses on many mirroless cameras.  I'm not familiar with your camera, but I'd be surprised if you didn't have any focusing aid available.

> Is the quality of those lenses, after adapting, at least acceptable, or is not worth the investment/trouble?

I can't recall encountering a bad 50/1.4-2 lens, so I'd expect the 50/1.8 to be worth using.  Most old 70-210/4-5.6 lenses I've used have been unimpressive, but you may be pleasantly surprised.  That is part of the fun of trying out old lenses.

Answer (score 1):

By chance I also have a Praktica kit left by my father, and some Micro 4/3 gear and adapters.  I also have an old Pentax lens which works just fine on the Praktica.  I don't have an adapter for this combination, but Praktica and old Pentax were so called M42 mount, so what you want will probably be called an M42 to micro 4/3 adapter.